# TinyBox POST form serialized into Array couses error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

When I use the following code, it works as expected:

```
TINY.box.show({url:target, post:$("form[name='currentSearch']").serialize(), 
width:650, mask:true, close:true, maskid:'boxMask', boxid:'popupBox', 
openjs:function(){initialiseDataTable()}});
```

When I use array instead `$("form[name='currentSearch']").serialize()` like this:

```
var postData = $("form[name='currentSearch']").serializeArray();

postData.push({flag : '1'});

TINY.box.show({url:target, post:postData, width:650, mask:true, close:true, maskid:'boxMask', 
boxid:'popupBox', openjs:function(){initialiseDataTable()}});
```

I'm getting error:

```
NS_ERROR_XPC_JSOBJECT_HAS_NO_FUNCTION_NAMED: 'JavaScript component does not have a method named: "available"' when calling method: [nsIInputStream::available]
[Break On This Error]   

...',c,true); x.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'...
```

I preffer to use an "array" as it is easier and more elegant way than adding dynamic inputs to the form. However I'm not that in JavaScript therefore could someone englighten me why this problem occures and is there a possibility to post the array?

This is the tinybox code where I think the error occures:

```
var x=window.XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');

x.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(x.readyState==4&&x.status==200){p.style.backgroundImage=''; TINY.box.psh(x.responseText,a,w,h)}
};

if(k){
    x.open('POST',c,true); x.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); x.send(k)
}else{
    x.open('GET',c,true); x.send(null)
}
```

Comment: have you tried with `postData['flag'] = 1;`?

Comment: @code-jaff just tired that and also without the flag, only `$form.serializeArry()`. That haven't work, but console don't give error any more. Any clue ?

Comment: @code-jaff it makes the page unresponsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems TinyBox doesn't use jQuery, therefore however you need to serialize the array which can then be used with the request. jQuery [param](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) comes handy in this case. This is what jQuery internally does when an array is being passed to `$.ajax`

```
var formData = $("form[name='currentSearch']").serializeArray();
formData.push({name : 'flag', value : '1'});
var postData = $.param(formData); // serialize it

TINY.box.show({url:target, post:postData, width:650, mask:true, close:true, maskid:'boxMask', 
boxid:'popupBox', openjs:function(){initialiseDataTable()}});
```